# How to check programatically if Debugbar is installed?

Tags: laravel

Which is best way in laravel 9 app to check programatically if Debugbar(and its functions are available) installed in current installation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running `$debugbarIsInstalled = class_exists(Debugbar::class)`

when return true means Debugbar is installed

Comment: Doesn't `Debugbar::class` throw an error when the class `Debugbar` is actually missing ? I think it should be `class:exsists('Package\Namespace\Debugbar')` instead

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I dont use debugbar in my project and using class_exists() will return false , no error thrown, but you can also check if using class namespace `class_exists('Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facades\Debugbar')` and will return false when not installed.  ... by the way `class:exists( ... ) will throw error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bound method to see if it's bound to the Laravel container.

```php
if (app()->bound('debugbar')) {
    // Now you can safely use Debugbar methods without the need to import a class that may or may not exists.
    app('debugbar')->startMeasure('render','Time for rendering');
    app('debugbar')->stopMeasure('render')
}
```